# Zsh: Prefer `cd` over commands

Tags: zsh

I'm enjoying zsh's feature to be able to navigate as

```
/
usr
..
```

The only issue is, when there is a command with the same name as a directory, it executes the command. Does Zsh have an option, or otherwise, to prefer cd'ing over commands, and maybe execute commands with `command COMMAND` if I want to execute that command? :)

Comment: I guess you could remove everything from your PATH?